# how to access parents controller data within component in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I have been told to incorporate AngularJS's `component` into my app. Before using components, I had two controllers, `patentList` and `patentItem`. When a user clicked on an item from the `patent list`, it would load more details on that specific `patent item`.

Now I have included the controllers in the `components`, data is failing to populate the `patent item` table. This is down to (I think) that the `patent item` is a child of `patent list` and I was able to access the parents data.

When I log the selected item, it shows with all properties and values.
[image: console log of item selected]

**My question is**, how do I access the data of parent `controller` now I have used `components`? Any help would be greatly appreciated

**list-patents**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in $ctrl.patents">
    <td ng-click="$ctrl.select(x)"><a ui-sref="patents.list.item({id: x.id})">{{x.applicationNumber}}</a></td>
    <td ng-bind="x.clientRef"></td>
    <td ng-bind="x.currentRenewalCost">$</td>
    <td ng-bind="x.costBandEndDate"></td>
    <td ng-bind="x.renewalCostNextStage"></td>
    <td ng-bind="x.renewalDueDate"></td>
</tr>
```

**patent-item**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in $ctrl.patentItem">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.patentApplicationNumber"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.clientRef"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.renewalStatus"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.costBandEndDate"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.renewalCostNextStage"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.renewalDueDate"></td>
</tr>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {

    app.component('patentList', {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/list-patents.htm",
        controller: function(loadPatentsService, loadPatentItemService) {

            var vm = this;

            vm.select = function(item) { 
               vm.patentItem = loadPatentItemService.select(item);
               console.log(item)
            }
        }
    })
});

app.component('patent', {
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/patent-item.htm",  
    controller: function(patentTabService, loadPatentItemService) {

        var vm = this;

       //LOAD OF CODE FOR A TAB PANEL

    }
})
```

---

```
app.factory('loadPatentItemService', function() {

    var factory = {};

        factory.select = function(item) {
            factory.storeSelect = [];
            selectedItem = item; 
            factory.storeSelect.push(selectedItem)
            return [selectedItem];
        }      

    return factory;

})

app.factory('patentTabService', function() {

    var factory = {};

        //CODE RELATED TO THE TAB PANEL

    return factory;

});
```

Comment: Why is the definition of the `patentList` component inside a config block? Also please show the state table for the router.

Answer (score 2):

## Intercomponent Communication

This can be achieved in a component by providing an object mapping for the `require` property. The object keys specify the property names under which the required controllers (object values) will be bound to the requiring component's controller.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Intercomponent Communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$emit/$broadcast` with `$scope.$on`

> [here is the plunker for your reference](http://plnkr.co/edit/am6IDw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$broadcast` and  `$on`

```
$scope.$broadcast ('key', {data: value}); //to set the value in parent 

 $scope.$on('key', function (event, data) {}); // to get the value in child
```